# MySQL Group by only if condition

Tags: mysql

I'm having hard time trying to find if I can do this.
So, from one table, I want to use GROUP BY only if the w.type is 'object' the other object don't have to be grouped.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number, w.name, w.type
FROM storage AS s
LEFT JOIN weapon AS w ON w.id=s.weapon_id
WHERE s.owner_id = 'ID'
GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY w.type
```

As you can see, this query group by everything.

I tried with UNION but it seems compromised because the double query is on the same table. And I looked for Case, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Thanks for reading !

Edit : 
This is for displaying inventory in game. Each weapons buckler are unique but you can have few different weapons with the same w.name.
Objects don't have this constraint, I need them group by and show to the player the number of the same item.

Player will see this :

Player Inventory

- Weapon

Diamond Sword, Iron Sword, Iron Sword

- Object

Apple x2, Pear x3, Egg x1

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make the question a lot clearer

Comment: Why do you think UNIONing two queries on the same table "compromises" the UNION query?

Comment: I updated, is it enough to understand ? Sorry I'm not so fluent

Comment: Why don't You add explicit `WHERE w.type ='object'`

Comment: I tried Union and it shows me unexpected error, my order by need to be at the end only and I had to rename my table s2 and w2 and the result were awful, object were grouped but my weapon were all grouped together. I maybe made a mistake ? Trying it again

Comment: Because I need to show other type too with same constraint except for the group by @ad4s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you've tried a UNION, but unless I'm just tired and missing something, does this not work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number, w.name, w.type 
FROM storage AS s 
LEFT JOIN weapon AS w ON w.id=s.weapon_id 
WHERE s.owner_id = 'ID' AND w.type = 'Object' 
GROUP BY s.name 
UNION
SELECT 1 as number, w.name, w.type 
FROM storage AS s 
LEFT JOIN weapon AS w ON w.id=s.weapon_id 
WHERE s.owner_id = 'ID' AND w.type != 'Object' 
GROUP BY w.id
ORDER BY w.type
```

In the second select, the group by would be a unique identifier - I'm assuming name and type would be sufficient, but I'm shooting blind without seeing data

Comment: Since the latter part has an aggregate function but no group by, it will give a single row that has the count of all non "Object" items, and an (effectively) random name and type of one of them. _You don't actually need the count in the latter part; just `1 as number`._

Comment: Exactly what cames out @Uueerdo

Comment: If I put a group by w.id for second* part does it will work ?

Comment: Note @Uuerrdo's point on the "Count" too  - I haven't changed that, but it could just as well be `SELECT 1 as number`, as no aggregation exists in that second query.

Comment: Will this will work in mysql 5.7 with sql mode set to "full group by"? This mode is set as default